# Как сделать так изображения?

Tags: html, css, css3, scss

Сижу ломаю голову, как их так сделать, пробовал и flex, можно конечно сделать через position relative, но как-то слегка извращенно. Есть способ попроще?
Т.е, мне даны такие фотографии, их нужно расставить так, как на картинке[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну вот мне даны эти фотографии и мне нужно их построить также, как и на фото

Comment: column-count: ..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
const generateImgBlock = () => `<div class="img-container">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/${Math.ceil(Math.random()*100+200)}/${Math.ceil(Math.random()*300+150)}"/>
  </div>`

document.querySelector(".gallery").innerHTML = Array(30).fill('').reduce((sum) => sum + generateImgBlock(), "");
```

```css
:root {
  --cols-count: 4;
}

body {
  background-color: #022;
}

.gallery {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 15px auto;
  column-count: var(--cols-count);
  column-gap: 17px;
  column-width: calc(100% / var(--cols-count));
}

.img-container img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 17px;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery"></div>
```

Comment: А без random как сделать можно? Просто в js, как-то еще плаваю(
Просто мне нужно, чтобы именно свои иконки, и в количестве 12 шт

Comment: Просто удалите весь js, который тут приведен, и поместите свои картинки в блок `<div class="gallery"></div>`